# Meaning of "go boil some milk, pastor"

Tags: dialogue, black-earth-rising

I have a problem understanding this verbal confrontation:

In the *Black Earth Rising* series, a lawyer is hired by dangerous men, represented by a priest. But it seems that they refuse to pay for the service, while the lawyer demands the payment or he will turn against his former client. At the end of this conversation we can hear this:

> *Lawyer:* Pay the piper, Padre. Or I'll pipe the rats right back.
> *Priest:* Actually, I'm a pastor.
> *Lawyer:* Yeah? **Then go boil some milk.**

The first sentence is an obvious reference to the fairy tale about [Pied Piper of Hamelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied_Piper_of_Hamelin), in which a piper uses magical flute to lure the rats out of town, but the citizens refuse to pay him, so he uses his magic on their children taking them away too. So the quite obvious meaning is "pay for the provided service or face the dire consequences".

The quick google search for "pastor" + "boiling milk" only shows the Bible fragment about "not boiling a young goat in its mother's milk", but I'm not sure how this is relevant to the plot.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[Pasteurization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasteurization) is a process most commonly done to milk, where something is mildly heated to extend its shelflife by destroying some bacteria. The process was invented by Louis Pasteur.

This sounds like pastor. The character makes a joke, by intentionally mistaking a pastor as someone who pasteurizes milk.

Comment: Oh, geeez.... so simple! Thanks, I was barking under the completely wrong tree!

Comment: Hmph.  I'm science-minded, and I still thought this joke was obscure.

Comment: Pasteurization is named after Louis Pasteur, so the pun should be pastor and Pasteur, not pastor and Pasteurizer..

Comment: "Obscure" is charitable. It's not clear that there's any category of clergyman who would identify with "pastor" but object to the idiomatic and generic "padre"; and having "a pastor" call "Pasteurize" to mind is a real stretch. It's the kind of attempted humour that leaves even people who get it wondering if that's what the author really meant, because it just doesn't work that well.

Comment: @CCTO the priest is from Arica (Rwanda/Congo) so possibly that he could not understand the "Padre" generic meaning. Pastor->pasteurize is indeed quite obscure, but then the discussion was quite heated, so it seems like it was a lame attempt at insult rather than witted pun

Comment: @CCTO, "Padre" or "Father" is a term of address for a Catholic or Angelican clergyman. A Protestant pastor would likely object to being addressed as such, hence his attempt to correct the lawyer. But the lawyer is just being dismissive with his joke.

Comment: @CCTO As someone raised protestant, "Padre" and "Father" are not at all generic to me. They read as specifically Catholic in my mind. I never once heard a pastor at my church referred to as Padre or Father, so it seems plausible to me that they would object (mildly) to that form of address.

Comment: Within the British military, 'padre' is a very standard way to informally refer to or address a military chaplain (the Royal Navy would understand 'padre' but more commonly use 'bish', I think) without specifically indicating a Catholic chaplain. I don't know if the same is true in the US or elsewhere.

Comment: The surname "Pasteur" means shepherd, as does the title "Pastor". I assume they are etymologically related to "pasture", a meadow

Comment: @M.A.Golding: "pasteur" means "pastor" in French. If the character is from a francophone part of Africa, like Rwanda or Congo, the pun is making sense.

Comment: "Padre" is of course just Spanish for "father" (whether a priest or an actual parental unit) so it's a little unusual to hear it in a French-speaking country - would be more common where Spanish is the - (I was about to say "lingua franca", but that just makes it French again - you know what I meant.)

Comment: This especially a stretch because pasteurization doesn't involve boiling the milk, just quickly heating it to the point where any bacteria will die

Answer (score 1):

Haven't watched the series, but since the lawyer says "Padre" when addressing the priest, I'm assuming at least one of them speaks **Spanish**.

In Spanish (maybe in other languages as well), "pastor" means shepherd, and shepherds take care of milk-producing animals, so "go boil some milk" could be understood as **"mind your own business"**.

Comment: Padre seems to just be a US slang/colloquial term for 'minister of undefined sect'. They used to use it way back in the John Wayne movies - both cowboy & WWII.

Comment: I have to agree with @Tetsujin here - the priest is from Africa (most likely either Rwanda or the Democratic Republic of Congo) and the lawyer was British, so I doubt that either of them speaks Spanish. *Padre* is quite obvious slang for "priest", that is understandable even for English-speaker.

Comment: Well now I know what to call someone whose either a shepard or a goatherd.

Comment: @Joshua `pastor` in Latin means... "shepherd".

Comment: @RonJohn: But what's the latin for goatherd?

Comment: @Joshua I used Google to find the root of "pastor"; you can do the same for "goatherd".

Comment: @RonJohn: In this case Google doesn't know (it output the latin for "one goat") but I'm expecting it to also be pastor.

Comment: @Joshua  https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=la&text=goatherd%0Ashepherd&op=translate

Comment: Regardless of the linguistic stuff, boiling milk is not something that shepherds are known for doing.

Comment: @Yasskier "_Padre_ is quite obvious slang for priest" Correct, and many Protestant pastors object to being called "priest", distancing themselves from the Catholic/Anglican traditions.